# Linux user with numerical name found and can't find who is it

Tags: linux, users

Simple and fast question:

```
kevin@pc:/usr/lib/jvm$ ls -l
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25 Feb 20 17:31 default-java -> java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Apr 23 20:34 java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-11-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jun 12 15:25 java-11-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 8  668  668 4096 Jun 12 12:12 jdk-11.0.3
```

Who/what is this 668 user?? I'm the only one using this machine.

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep 668
```

Doesn't show anything with the number 668

Additional info: I installed jdk-11.0.3_linux-x64_bin.deb via GUI

Comment: I'm tempted to say somebody ran `chown 668` instead of `chmod 668` but that doesn't really add up.

Comment: @JeffSchaller  I just double clicked on jdk-11.0.3_linux-x64_bin.deb and installed it via GUI

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you are seeing is files / directories belonging to a non-existent user.  Linux mostly uses numbers to represent users rather than names usernames are effectively a lookup to a number.  If the UID (number) doesn't exist in `/etc/passwd` (or other nsswitch mechanisms) this won't prevent files from belonging to that numeric userid.

Examples of causes include:

- At some stage there may have been a user with uid `668`, but that user has since been deleted.
- Extracting an archive which uses UID's not names (eg tar file).
- Simply setting the ownership with `chown`
- Plugging a hard drive from another computer

Comment: Or the files have been extracted from some archive, preserving the UID stored in the archive.

Comment: @Kusalananda Now I think of it there's a massive number of reasons this can happen. No point in listing them all, but might as well give some examples.

Answer (score 1):

> I installed jdk-11.0.3_linux-x64_bin.deb via GUI

The "tar" utility program and other such programs that extract files from a master combined file (in tar's case, called an archive) typically have two modes for user IDs: 1) have all the extracted files belong to the user doing the extraction.  2) restore the user IDs that existed when that master file was created.  Mode 2 requires root access.  The problem is first that the user IDs are stored as user *numbers*, not as text.  When this archive was made, the jdk directory belonged to user number 668.  But secondly, even if the master file included a textual name (e.g., "bob") that wouldn't help much as there's probably no "bob" on your machine, and if there was that person probably wouldn't have anything to do with jdk and shouldn't have automatic access to delete and modify jdk.

(While it then sounds useless for archives to contain user ID numbers, remember you can also use tar to snapshot, store, and move around files on your local systems where a given user ID number when an archive file is created is probably still the same user when you're extracting files from the archive later.)

So ultimately I'd say that your installation GUI made a mistake in restoring user IDs when it shouldn't have.  Instead it should have set the user ID for all files to some other ID.